# When do we use 〜どおりに instead of 〜のとおりに after nouns?

Tags: grammar

I noticed that in the case of nouns, we can use either of these:

1. Ｎのとおりに
2. Ｎどおりに

But this seems to be case-specific.

When or in which circumstances do we use the latter?

Comment: Either will do.

Answer (score 1):

You can use “のとおりに” after any noun phrase.
However, it may sound slightly awkward when used after a short noun.
This form can be analyzed as:

> “Nのとおりに" 
>   = 名詞 “N” + 助詞 “の” + 名詞 “とおり” + 助詞 “に”

“どおりに” is used like a postposition.
Usually it is used after a short noun.
Analysis:

> “Nどおりに” 
>   = 名詞 “N” + 名詞 “どおり” + 助詞 “に”